# Sorting by does not work when I output to excel

Tags: pandas, sorting

I have the following code and when I export my data to an excel the sorting I used does not work:

```
df.sort_values(['ID1','ID2'],ascending=True).groupby('ID1').

df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DOCUMENT.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Could you explain to me why this does not work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reassign to the variable you output to excel or use the `inplace` argument

e.g

```
df.sort_values(['ID1','ID2'],ascending=True,inplace=True).groupby('ID1').
```

or

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID1','ID2'],ascending=True).groupby('ID1').
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is the error I get back: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'